# Function to flag duplicates in within query Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, duplicates, arguments

I would like to write a function that flags duplicates in specified columns in postgresql.

For example, if I had the following table:

```
country | landscape | household
--------------------------------
TZA     | L01       | HH02
TZA     | L01       | HH03
KEN     | L02       | HH01
RWA     | L03       | HH01
```

I would like to be able to run the following query:

```
SELECT country,
       landscape,
       household,
       flag_duplicates(country, landscape) AS flag
FROM mytable
```

And get the following result:

```
country | landscape | household | flag
---------------------------------------
TZA     | L01       | HH02      | duplicated
TZA     | L01       | HH03      | duplicated
KEN     | L02       | HH01      |
RWA     | L03       | HH01      |
```

Inside the body of the function, I think I need something like:

```
IF (country || landscape IN (SELECT country || landscape FROM mytable
                            GROUP BY country || landscape)
    HAVING count(*) > 1) THEN 'duplicated'
ELSE NULL
```

But I am confused about how to pass all of those as arguments.  I appreciate the help.  I am using postgresql version 9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a function to accomplish that. Using function for every row in result set is not so good idea because of performance. A way better solution is use pure SQL (even with subqueries) and give database engine chance to optimize it. In your very example it should be something like that:

```
SELECT t.country,t.landscape,t.household,case when duplicates.count>1 then 'duplicate'end 
FROM mytable t JOIN ( 
SELECT count(household) FROM mytable GROUP BY country,landscape
) duplicates ON duplicates.country=t.country AND duplicates.landscape=t.landscape
```

which produces exactly the same result.

Update - if You want to use function at all cost, here is working example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION find_duplicates(arg_country varchar, arg_landscape varchar) returns varchar AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN count(household)>1 THEN 'duplicated' END FROM mytable
    WHERE country=arg_country AND landscape=arg_landscape
    GROUP BY country,landscape;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  *,
  (count(*) over (partition by country, landscape)) > 1 as flag
from
  mytable;
```

For function look at the [@MarcinH answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40939537/593144) but add [`stable`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-volatility.html) to the function's definition to make its calls faster.